# When did our neutrino detectors become sensitive enough to detect supernovas in the core of the Milky Way?

Tags: supernova, neutrinos

When did our neutrino detectors become sensitive enough to be able to detect supernovas occurring in the Core of the Milky Way galaxy?
I know the answer is well before 1987, because we detected the neutrinos from that supernova which was 6-7 times further.

Answer (score 12):

IMB was running from 1982, and we know that this could detect supernova neutrino because it detected 8 in 1987.

Previous scintillation methods depended on the detection of neutrinos from a neighbouring nuclear reactor, and were not sensitive enough to detect solar neutrinos.  Radiochemical techniques do not give results in real time, so could not detect a short "spike" from a core collapse.

So the first methods that could detect neutrios in real time was the Cherenkov detector at IMB in 1982.  Kamiokande uses similar technology, but came online in 1985 but was only just reaching full operation in Feb 1987.